# How to show that dates are in descending order

Tags: ruby

I have an array of dates in string format:

```
[ 0] "06 May 14",
[ 1] "11 Apr 14",
[ 2] "11 Apr 14",
[ 3] "11 Apr 14",
[ 4] "10 Apr 14",
[ 5] "09 Apr 14",
[ 6] "09 Apr 14",
[ 7] "09 Apr 14",
[ 8] "09 Apr 14",
[ 9] "08 Apr 14",
[10] "08 Apr 14"
```

I need to find a method of proving that the dates are descending.

I have tried to convert them to a date format using

```
datesarray.map { |s, i| [Date.parse(s).to_time.to_i, i] }
```

which gives:

```
[ 0] [
    [0] 1399330800,
    [1] nil
],
[ 1] [
    [0] 1397170800,
    [1] nil
],
[ 2] [
    [0] 1397170800,
    [1] nil
],
[ 3] [
    [0] 1397170800,
    [1] nil
],
[ 4] [
    [0] 1397084400,
    [1] nil
],
[ 5] [
    [0] 1396998000,
    [1] nil
],
[ 6] [
    [0] 1396998000,
    [1] nil
],
[ 7] [
    [0] 1396998000,
    [1] nil
],
[ 8] [
    [0] 1396998000,
    [1] nil
],
[ 9] [
    [0] 1396911600,
    [1] nil
],
[10] [
    [0] 1396911600,
    [1] nil
```

However, it seems to convert it to an integer only temporarily, and then it changes back to string.

Any help is great.

Thanks,
Devon

Comment: What do you mean by "convert it to an integer only temporarily"? you want the result to be a list of integers?

Answer (score 3):

```
require "date"

[
  "06 May 14",
  "11 Apr 14",
  "11 Apr 14",
  "11 Apr 14",
  "10 Apr 14",
  "09 Apr 14",
  "09 Apr 14",
  "09 Apr 14",
  "09 Apr 14",
  "08 Apr 14",
  "08 Apr 14",
]
.map{|s| Date.parse(s)}.each_cons(2).all?{|d1, d2| d1 >= d2}
# => true
```

Comment: Wouldn’t `dates.sort_by { |s| Date.parse s } == dates.reverse` be sufficient?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`sort_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by):

```
dates= ["06 May 14","11 Apr 14","11 Apr 14","11 Apr 14","10 Apr 14","09 Apr 14","09 Apr 14","08 Apr 14","08 Apr 14"]
dates.sort_by { |x| -Date.parse(x).to_time.to_i }
=> ["06 May 14", "11 Apr 14", "11 Apr 14", "11 Apr 14", "10 Apr 14", "09 Apr 14", "09 Apr 14", "08 Apr 14", "08 Apr 14"]
```

To show that the input list is ordered by date in descending order, compare it to the sorted array:

```
dates.sort_by { |x| -Date.parse(x).to_time.to_i } == dates
=> true
```

Answer (score 0):

> However, it seems to convert it to an integer only temporarily

This is because you are not replacing array elements with parsed dates. You are just converting them for 1 time.

Use `map!` for replacing array values too. Here:

```
datesarray = ["06 May 14", "11 Apr 14", "11 Apr 14", "11 Apr 14", "10 Apr 14", "09 Apr 14", "09 Apr 14", "09 Apr 14", "09 Apr 14", "08 Apr 14", "08 Apr 14"]
datesarray.map { |s, i| [Date.parse(s).to_time.to_i, i] }
datesarray
#  => ["06 May 14", "11 Apr 14", "11 Apr 14", "11 Apr 14", "10 Apr 14", "09 Apr 14", "09 Apr 14", "09 Apr 14", "09 Apr 14", "08 Apr 14", "08 Apr 14"] 

datesarray.map! { |s, i| [Date.parse(s).to_time.to_i, i] }
datesarray
# => [[1399314600, nil], [1397154600, nil], [1397154600, nil], [1397154600, nil], [1397068200, nil], [1396981800, nil], [1396981800, nil], [1396981800, nil], [1396981800, nil], [1396895400, nil], [1396895400, nil]]
```

**Sorting array:**

```
datesarray.sort_by(&:to_time) # String#to_time works only with Rails
# => ["08 Apr 14", "08 Apr 14", "09 Apr 14", "09 Apr 14", "09 Apr 14", "09 Apr 14", "10 Apr 14", "11 Apr 14", "11 Apr 14", "11 Apr 14", "06 May 14"]
```

**Reverse sorting:**

```
datesarray.sort_by(&:to_time).reverse # String#to_time works only with Rails
# => ["06 May 14", "11 Apr 14", "11 Apr 14", "11 Apr 14", "10 Apr 14", "09 Apr 14", "09 Apr 14", "09 Apr 14", "09 Apr 14", "08 Apr 14", "08 Apr 14"]
```

Comment: note: to_time is a rails monkey patch to String. http://apidock.com/rails/String/to_time

Answer (score 0):

Sorting takes forever and creates a temporary array. Just step through the array, comparing each date with the one before:

```
require 'date'

def descending?(arr)
  last = convert(arr.first)
  arr.all? do |s|
    l = last
    last = convert(s)
    last <= l
  end
end

def convert(s)
  Date.strptime(s, '%d %b %y')
end

arr = ["06 May 14", "11 Apr 14", "11 Apr 14", "11 Apr 14",
       "10 Apr 14", "09 Apr 14", "09 Apr 14", "09 Apr 14",
       "09 Apr 14", "08 Apr 14", "08 Apr 14"]

descending?(arr)
  #=> true

arr[0], arr[1] = arr[1], arr[0]
arr
  #=> ["11 Apr 14", "06 May 14", "11 Apr 14", "11 Apr 14",
  #    "10 Apr 14", "09 Apr 14", "09 Apr 14", "09 Apr 14",
  #    "09 Apr 14", "08 Apr 14", "08 Apr 14"]

descending?(arr)
  #=> false
```

Alternatively, you could write `convert` as follows:

```
MON_MAP =
  { 'Jan'=>'00', 'Feb'=>'01', 'Mar'=>'02', 'Apr'=>'03', 'May'=>'04', 'Jun'=>'05',
    'Jul'=>'06', 'Aug'=>'07', 'Sep'=>'08', 'Oct'=>'09', 'Nov'=>'10', 'Dec'=>'11' }

def convert(s)
  "#{ s[-2,2] } #{ MON_MAP[s[3,3]] } #{ s[0,2] }"
end

convert("11 Apr 14")
  #=> "14 03 11"
```